# How to overwrite on an insert into a Sql Server table if primary key already exists?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has a primary key column. If I'm entering a new update into a table, the primary key of which already exists as an entry, should I delete the previous entry prior to insertion, or is there a way to overwrite the existing entry?

Comment: use `merge` not `insert`. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: This seems like the right answer, definitely helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using entity framework with .net go for a delete then insert as this will not confuse EF's object identifiers which are held in memory.

Comment: Is there an optimal way to do this. Or should I just do: select to check if it exists, delete if it exists, proceed with insert?

Comment: If you are using entity framework, the easy way is to get the object by the key. as you say, if it exists delete it then go for an insert. This won't be the optimal way as there will be 2 database calls (1 to get and the other to insert) not to mention the object serialisation and conversion. The optimal way is as @Daniel E. suggests and use the merge statement and you could put this in a stored procedure and use it from Entity framework anyhow. You would only ever have 1 database call.